# Is "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE" in store procedure is deprecated for Google Cloud sql 5.6+?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

Question: Is "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE" in store procedure is deprecated for Google Cloud sql 5.6+?

I am using an old instance of google cloud i.e 5.5 and as it needs to upgrade to 5.6. Documentation states we can't use "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE" for a transaction. Does it mean we can't use it in store procedure?

I am referencing to this [Unsupported statements](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/features#2nd-gen-unsupported).

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: Stored procedure and transaction are not relative. Simply do not start transaction in SP (or check that there is no active transaction in the point of a code where it calls this SP), and use CTT freely.

Comment: As you pointed out, there are various [unsupported statements](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/features#2nd-gen-unsupported). One of them is `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` statement inside transactions, but you have to take into account it is not related to your version, but rather the generation of your Cloud SQL instance. If your Cloud SQL instance is a 2nd-generation instance, `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` statements inside transactions are not supported because 2nd-generation instances uses GTID replication. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is deprecated in the my sql version MySQL 8.0.13. Check this documentation from MySQL 8.0.

At this time, google uses MySQL version 8.0.26-google

Check your my sql version using this command:

```
Select version()
```

[MySQL 8.0 Temporary Tables (Official documentation)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html)

[image]